# Padding Bootstrap Thumbnails

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, thumbnails

I am using thumbnails in bootstrap. I have been able to correct the padding to my liking on the sides, but not below it. This is a big problem on mobile as it's way too wide for my liking.

Code:

```
<div class="col-5-gutter">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="images/Thumbnail_Placeholder.png" alt="Thumbnail Image 1">
<div class="caption">
<h3>Text</h3>
<p>Text.</p>      
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-5-gutter">
<div class="col-md-4">
<div class="thumbnail"><img src="images/Thumbnail_Placeholder.png" alt="Thumbnail Image 1">
<div class="caption">
<h3>Text Here</h3>
<p>Text Here</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.col-5-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the problem a bit more! what is the exact problem you are facing?

Comment: So I was able to correct the padding on the left and right of the column, by reducing it to 5px, however there is large padding at the bottom. Here are some screen shots:

Desktop: https://www.screencast.com/t/zGvPFzFlDH
Mobile: https://www.screencast.com/t/2qM59NH6ygWF

Anyway I can reduce that thick black padding? padding-bottom and margin-bottom doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: But what is the actual issue??

Comment: Sorry see my edited comment above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was `margins`not`padding`. However the problem was in the thumbnail class:

```
.thumbnail {
margin-bottom: 5px;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

for effect only at big screen use @media in CSS :

```
@media ( min-width : 992px) {
     .col-5-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
        padding-right:5px;
        padding-left:5px;
        padding-bottom: 5px;
    }
}
```

992px is for example, can use your prefer size

Comment: There is still the same amount of padding at the bottom, see screenshot: https://www.screencast.com/t/zGvPFzFlDH

Comment: this padding for thumbnail class ,this have 20px padding

Answer (score 0):

I think that you should be thinking of `margins` instead of `padding` when you want space outside an element. So I would suggest adding the CSS property `margin-bottom:5px`, add the property to the CSS classs like.

```
.col-5-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

If this does not work, then some other CSS class must be overriding the margin-bottom. Then please modify the class to.

```
.col-5-gutter > [class*='col-'] {
    padding-right:5px;
    padding-left:5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
```

I was not able to replicate your issue in my bootstrap snippet, it may be due to some other CSS class.

Below is a snippet demonstrating `margin-bottom`.

---

```css
.col-5-gutter div[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-5-gutter">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Thumbnail Image 1">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Text</h3>
        <p>Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-5-gutter">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Thumbnail Image 1">
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>Text Here</h3>
          <p>Text Here</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

Also I find that the HTML is `weird` Should the HTML layout be like this (if wrong please ignore this section).

---

```css
.col-5-gutter div[class*='col-'] {
  padding-right: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px !important;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-5-gutter">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Thumbnail Image 1">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Text</h3>
        <p>Text.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="col-5-gutter">
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="Thumbnail Image 1">
      <div class="caption">
        <h3>Text Here</h3>
        <p>Text Here</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

---

Comment: You are right, along with the other person below. It should have been 'margins', but also in the thumbnail class.

Comment: It is - thank you! And yes the HTML was weird, just the way I posted it on Stackoverflow, it's just like yours otherwise.

Comment: @Phil You're welcome, if the issue is solved you can close this answer!